# How to restart a React Joyride Tour after it has ended in a functional Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to set the run attribute of Joyride back to false after the tour has ended, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried using their callback functions, but I can't find an example for when you are using functional components. Here's my code for the Joyride component:

```
<Joyride
    run={run}
    steps={steps}
    debug
    continuous
    showSkipButton
    showProgress
    callback={handleJoyrideCallback()}
    styles={{
      options: {
        arrowColor: theme.palette.common.white,
        primaryColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
        textColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
        width: 500,
        zIndex: 10000,
      },
      buttonNext: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
        border: "none",
        borderRadius: 0,
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
        "&:focus": {
          outline: "none !important",
        },
      },
      buttonBack: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.dark,
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: 5,
      },
      buttonClose: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.dark,
        height: 14,
        padding: 15,
        position: "absolute",
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 14,
      },
    }}
  />
```

And here's the callback function:

```
const handleJoyrideCallback = (data) => {
const { status, type } = data;
const finishedStatuses = [STATUS.FINISHED, STATUS.SKIPPED];
if (finishedStatuses.includes(status)) {
  setRun(false);
}
```

};

And the stuff for setRun:

```
  const [run, setRun] = useState(false);
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with the way you're updating the state.

Comment: Well the issue is, when I call the handleJoyrideCallback() function, I get this Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling the function
`handleJoyrideCallback in callback={handleJoyrideCallback()}`

You should use:
`callback={handleJoyrideCallback}`